# Another index outside the bounds of an array C# error >.<

Tags: indexoutofboundsexception

So I get an error on line 21 which is the if ("client".CompareTo(args[0]) == 0) line >.< No it's not my code but I would like to get it all working to study from it. It's basically a game client and server program for C# but it also uses a .bat? Like I said it's not my code so I'm unsure as to why the need for a .bat file, this is just useless information because I'm told by this forum to add more details lol, I just want to know how to fix the error on line 21.

```
        public static void Main(String[] args)
    {
        UDP_helper uh = new UDP_helper();
        try
        {
            //if (!Valid(args))      

            if ("client".CompareTo(args[0]) == 0) //<--- error is on this line
            {
                uh.sendToAddr = args[1];
                uh.sendToPort = int.Parse(args[2]);
            }
            else
                if ("server".CompareTo(args[0]) == 0)
                {
                    uh.IsServer = true;
                    uh.listenOnPort = int.Parse(args[1]);

                }
                else
                    if ("forward".CompareTo(args[0]) == 0)
                    {
                        uh.IsForward = true;
                        uh.listenOnPort = int.Parse(args[1]);
                        uh.forwardToAddr = args[2];
                        uh.forwardToPort = int.Parse(args[3]);
                        uh.listenWait = 600;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Usage: .exe sends multiple udp messages");
                        Console.WriteLine("Usage: .exe client sendtoaddr sendtoport");
                        Console.WriteLine("Usage: .exe server listenport");
                        Console.WriteLine("Usage: .exe forward listenport forwardtoaddr forwardtoport");
                        return;
                    }
            Console.WriteLine(args[0]);

            uh.Run();

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
            Console.Read();
        }
        return;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you have to pass an argument to the executable. There's no checking for args.Length, so when there's no parameter, it throws an exception. Try calling it with a *server* or *client* parameter.

You have the possible arguments listed down there:

```
Console.WriteLine("Usage: .exe sends multiple udp messages");
Console.WriteLine("Usage: .exe client sendtoaddr sendtoport");
Console.WriteLine("Usage: .exe server listenport");
Console.WriteLine("Usage: .exe forward listenport forwardtoaddr forwardtoport");
```

Comment: You misunderstand, it compiles and builds fine but when opening the exe that's when I get the error.

Comment: That's what I said. You have to run the exe the right way, ie. `nameoftheexe.exe server 7746` etc.

Comment: If you don't pass any arguments to the exe, it throws an exception, because there's no check for args.Length == 0, so you end up trying to get args[0] when there's no item in the array.

Comment: Well I want it to run as server and I have just been trying everything but I'm at a loss, sounds stupid but this is a bit more "advanced" than my knowledge currently hold lol.

Comment: How are you running the application? From Visual Studio? If so, you can add executable parameters in project Properties -> Debug -> Command line arguments.

Comment: Yup using VS2012, so just add server.exe server portnumber to it yes?

Comment: Actually, just `server portnumber`. That should be enough.

Comment: Thank you I love you in a non gay way it's working!!! I would vote this up but my reputation isn't high enough :(

Comment: Accepting the answer is quite enough :) Good luck with your endeavours :)